# need to write a code in assembly language is this correct

Tags: assembly, x86-16, equation, subtraction, divide

Need a code in assembly language to solve the equation
`z=(x+3)/2`
known that x=7

I tried using `div` but somebody said it is better use `sub` and loop
and I need to show the Decimal fractions

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data

x db 6
z db ?
.code
main proc
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax
mov ah,0
mov bl,2
mov al,x
add al,3
div bl
mov z,al
add z,48
mov dl,z
mov ah,2h
int 21h 



main endp
end main
```

Comment: _"known that m=7"_ I don't see any `m` being used anywhere.

Comment: An even better way to divide by 2 is `shr ax, 1`.

Comment: sorry it's x=7
where i but shr ax,1

Comment: If x is 7, just mov the 5 into the ax register and return.  :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is this correct?

No, because the question states that `x=7` and your program defines `x db 6`.

> ... and I need to show the Decimal fractions

If `x=7` then the expression `(x+3)/2` will not produce a fraction (the result is a plain 5).

However if we make the exercise a bit more interesting, we could allow for a range of inputs for the *x* in the equation. Then the only fraction that you could get from dividing by 2 would be **.5**.

### `x=7` and using division by 2

```
.data
  x db 7
  z db ?
.code
main proc
  mov ax, data
  mov ds, ax
  mov al, x
  add al, 3
  cbw
  mov bl, 2
  div bl        ; -> AL == 5
  mov z, al
  add al, '0'
  mov dl, al    ; -> DL == "5"
  mov ah, 02h   ; DOS.PrintChar
  int 21h
```

### `x=6` and replacing division by 2 with a shift to the right

```
.data
  x db 6
.code
main proc
  ...
  mov al, x
  add al, 3
  shr al, 1
  mov dx, '00'
  jnc Divisible
  mov dh, '5'
Divisible:
  add dl, al    ; -> DL == "4"
  mov ah, 02h   ; DOS.PrintChar
  int 21h
  mov dl, '.'   ; Decimal point
  int 21h
  mov dl, dh    ; -> DL == "5"
  int 21h
```

Here the shift to the right will produce a carry because `(x+3)` is an odd number. Therefore the result will show **.5**, else it would show **.0**.

You can run the above example with *x* ranging from 0 to 16. Results will vary from 1.5 to 9.5.